# Different nibs for different OS X versions

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, interface-builder

Is it possible somehow to have different nib files for different OS X versions? Because for example 10.6 does not have auto-layout function, while on 10.7 and 10.8 it is a great function. So if it is possible I could create one nib for 10.6 and another nib for 10.7 and 10.8.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Just create different NIB files, e.g. add the version at the end of the name of these files, then, at runtime, find out which OS X version the current system is running and programmatically load the right lib for the OS X version.

Doing that for the "main" NIB of your application would be rather difficult, though (it is possible, I have don that before, yet I don't recommend it). Just make your main NIB 10.6 compatible and only place the main menu into it, as well as the application delegate (if you want it to be created by the NIB file instead of creating it programmatically). Place all windows, views and other UI elements into separate NIB files and then within your application delegate, load the NIB files programmatically in a callback like `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`

Just look at [Apple's NIB File Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html), and search for "Loading Nib Files Programmatically". There are some helpful links to the methods needed for that, as well as some sample code for simple common cases.

Comment: So every UI element should be created in separate nib's, and at launch time if I it is for example 10.7 OS X then load all element's nibs that are created for 10.7 and if it is 10.6, load all element's nibs that are created for 10.6? And why you don't recommend to do it for main nib where all elements and everything is created? Then it would be only two nibs, that has to be loaded in dependence of OS X version. Sounds simplier, just actions while launching app would be more difficult.

Comment: @Julius: Because the main Nib is usually loaded automatically and loading the main Nib programmatically is much harder. You also don't need one Nib per UI element, you can have only three Nibs, Main, one with all 10.6 elements and one with all 10.7+ elements. There is no limit to the number of Windows, Views and other elements you can put into a single Nib. Also there is no need to put everything into the Main nib; it is enough to just put the application delegate and the main menu into the main Nib and put everything else (including the main window) into some other Nib file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just supply different NIB filenames when loading them. The one place where you can't do this is the application NIB, but it should be free of UI elements beside the menu bar, so just leave it springs-and-struts (ie not autolayout).

This may involve overriding `makeWindowControllers` or `windowNibName` on `NSDocument`, for example, in order to work on the NIB filename. See the documentation for more information about solving this for a particular class - it is definitely doable.